# Unity3d, cannot run the build on mac os

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just tried building my game on my MAC but failed. What I did is

=> File

=> Build & Settings

=> Choose MAC

=> Pick Up the Scene (I tried )

=> Build & Run

The game could be built, but not run. What happened is after I clicked the icon, a window jumped out but disappeared immediately..

Then I tried another way by using the terminal, cd to the game content folder, cd to MacOs folder, then ./ to launch my game. Finallly I got this feedback,

Failed to read file '/Users/Hoop22/Desktop/StudyUnity3DProject/StudyMultiplePlayerFPS/Builds/MultiFPS.app/Contents/Data/mainData' because it is corrupted.

(Filename: Line: 442)

PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics settings: Could..... not preload global game manager #0 i=0 Failed to initialize engine

By the way, I tried building it with web player, and everything was fine.......

Could some body please give me a hand?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data is corrupted. Maybe you've got some aggresive and broken antivirus (or just a virus)? Was the build moved to this computer by network (ftp, samba, http etc.)? Is your license ehem... legit? [Cracks cause problems](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/error-could-not-preload-global-game-manager-0.38135/#post-1033084).

A few things to try:

- Build the game to a different directory
- Log in as a different user to the same machine
- Reinstall unity3d